# Products photo slider on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, opencart

I want to do a slider with product photos like this: https://www.jacquemus.com/product/la-robe-camil-kaki/

Any idea to do this?

Comment: Please share your starting point. This is Q&A platform for Software problems.

Comment: Hi Maria, it is expected that you at least attempt to write the code yourself and if you get stuck with a specific programming problem, then come back with your code and the problem you are facing.  In it's current form, your question is way too broad and therefore off topic for SO

Answer (score 0):

But to answer your question, you can use the library like https://www.jssor.com/ This one especially is very comprehensive